# SAP DBTech JDBC: [1306]: return type mismatch:Procedure ARRAY_UNNEST_SIMPLE: Attribute name "id" different from Attribute name: ":ARRID"

Tags: hana

Hello everyone I am learning about SAP HANA. I'm having trouble at this error, I've been trying to figure out how to fix it but I haven't figured it out yet, I hope everyone will help. Thank you all.

```
DROP TYPE ttype;
CREATE TYPE ttype AS TABLE("ID" INT , "NAME" NVARCHAR(10));        
CREATE PROCEDURE ARRAY_UNNEST_SIMPLE(OUT rst ttype)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE arrid INTEGER ARRAY = ARRAY (1,2);
DECLARE arrname NVARCHAR(10) ARRAY = ARRAY('name1', 'name2', 'name3');
rst = UNNEST(:arrid, :arrname);
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the error is due to the mismatch of the column **names** that result from the `UNNEST` operation and the declared return table variable.

You can provide column names via the `AS ...` command parameter:

```
rst = UNNEST(:arrid, :arrname) AS (“ID”, “NAME”)
```

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand your example “sdada”. The main point is that the result set that you try to stick into the RETURN variables has the exact same structure as the declared return vars. Instead of the AS ... command you could also write an additional SELECT that projects the columns to the correct column names. That, of course, also uses the AS... syntax.

Comment: sorry bro. I am learning how to comment stackoverflow, I just used it a few days ago.

Comment: I have read sap hana document including e.g like this:
`CREATE PROCEDURE ARRAY_UNNEST_SIMPLE(OUT rst TTYPE)  
READS SQL DATA  
AS
BEGIN  
 DECLARE arr_id INTEGER ARRAY = ARRAY (1,2);  
DECLARE arr_name VARCHAR(10) ARRAY = ARRAY('name1', 'name2', 'name3');  
 rst = UNNEST(:arr_id, :arr_name);  
END;
`

Comment: And 
`---Result  
:ARR_ID  :ARR_NAME
-------------------
1      name1
2      name2
?      name3
`